# Barcode scanner does not scan characters correctly in android tab

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I am scanning the barcode that enter text correctly in desktops all browser but fails to scan the character correctly in android tab. I fixed this by removing caret position. Now I have added auto focus to my textbox and if scanner is plugged, it should scan the text field.After successful entering the first textbox, the focus should be on next textbox(password type). This time the the scanner should not be used, instead it should throw  the key pad.

How I can force the keypad?

Comment: I take it [tag:html], [tag:html5] and [tag:html5-canvas] are relevant tags seen as though you approved [this suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5772095)? I would have though [tag:android] would be more relevant??

Comment: @Lankymart Yes probably.

Comment: If your problem is to do with Android Tab (possibly the actionbar) then I'd suggest you at least use the [tag:android] tag (to get the right audience), have updated your question.

Comment: My updated question is general.